# MvvmCross Android binding Enabled not work with Click

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a `TextView` bound with Enabled, `Clickable` and Click. When the `activity` is loaded, Enabled & `Clickable` were bound to false value but the `TextView` cannot be disabled & still be clickable. After changed the bound value to true & then false, the `TextView` is disabled.

I found that the issue was related to binding the Click event. Once Click is bound, the mentioned issue occurs. Without binding the Click event, it works as expected.

In the following sample code, the first 2 `TextViews` are ok. The last one with binding Click does not work.

BTW, I have this issue with `TextInputEditText` instead. I found the situation applies to `TextView` as well so I use `TextView` for illustration.

```
         <TextView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="test textview can be disabled at load"
             style="@style/EntryTextStyle"
             local:MvxBind="       Enabled RouteMarker.ArrivalNotice" />
         <TextView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="test textview with no click command, can be disabled at load"
             style="@style/EntryTextStyle"
             local:MvxBind="       Enabled RouteMarker.ArrivalNotice;
                                   Clickable RouteMarker.ArrivalNotice" />
         <TextView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="test textview with click command cannot be disabled at load"
             style="@style/EntryTextStyle"
             local:MvxBind="       Enabled RouteMarker.ArrivalNotice;
                                   Clickable RouteMarker.ArrivalNotice;
                                   Click DoSomethingCommand" />

    private IMvxAsyncCommand _doSomethingCommand;
    public IMvxAsyncCommand DoSomethingCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _doSomethingCommand = _doSomethingCommand ?? new MvxAsyncCommand(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(10);
            });
            return _doSomethingCommand;
        }
    }
```

Any idea how to fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Stuart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569603/binding-the-enabled-property-of-a-android-button-with-the-mvvmcross) said, there are some interaction between `ICommand.CanExecute` and the `Enabled` property. Switching the binding to :

```
local:MvxBind="Click DoSomethingCommand;Enabled RouteMarker.ArrivalNotice;Clickable RouteMarker.ArrivalNotice;"
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQB8y.png).